# Grep for String and open at the corresponding line

Tags: linux, vim, command-line, grep, batch-processing

I'm having several occurrences of a specific string over several files in several lines obtained with `grep`.

```
$ grep -rn --include="*.cpp" mystring
lib/mlib/actionbuttonrule.cpp:300:  mystring Foobar...
lib/mlib/actionbuttonrule.cpp:314:  other mystring
lib/mlib/item.cpp:3025:             /* mystring**/
lib/mlib/item.cpp:3082:             mystring Foobar...
lib/mlib/item.cpp:3095:             Foo mystring bar
```

I'd like to open these files sequencially on the corresponding lines. I tried to do it with `vim`, but so far no success when it comes to open the line. 
Mustn't be `vim` or `grep`, but I'd assume there must be some kind of functionality out there...

Comment: Do you want to open for viewing the context? (grep has options to support that) Or do you want to open for editing interactively?

Comment: I need to edit it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can load your `grep` output in Vim's quickfix list with:

```
$ vim -q <(grep -rn --include="*.cpp" mystring)
```

Go to the next occurence with `:cn` and to the previous occurrence with `:cp`.

See `:help -q` and `:help quickfix`.

Comment: Missing -l flag to grep

Comment: @GillesQuenot, fixed.

Comment: why is `-l` needed? it worked for me without `-l` and doesn't work with `-l`... am using `gvim` if that makes a difference

Comment: `-l` shouldn't be required IMHO as quick fix should understand default `grep` output format.

Comment: Guys, `-l` is not needed at all, change reverted. Only `-r` and `-n` are really needed. `-n` for the line numbers, `-r` for a side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do

```
$ grep -rn --include="*.cpp" mystring > op
$ vim op
```

Then use `gF` and to come back to file op, use  <kbd>Ctrl + 6</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A trick to use vim as a pager is to pass it a hyphen character.  This causes it to read from STDIN instead of from file

```
grep -rn --include="*.cpp" mystring | vim -
```